# How to use a vector in a vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a for statement with a vector in a vector.

```
std::vector<std::string> array = {
    {"A", "a"},
    {"B", "b"},
    {"C", "c"}
};

for (std::string& a : array) {
    if (letter == a[1] || letter == a[0]) {
        std::cout << a[0] << ": " << a[1] << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

I am new to C++ and cannot figure out why it gives me errors about this.

---

Edit:

Error: `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type' (aka 'char'))`

Comment: `'A'`, `'a'`, and so on.

Comment: Post the error in your question. Also you might want to use some other name for your variable.

Comment: What are you intending to do with `{"A", "a"}`? Did you perhaps want to have a vector of `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`?

Comment: "How to use a vector in a vector" Do you mean "How to use a string in a vector"

Comment: What is `letter`?

Comment: a letter from the user's input

Comment: @Aftermathic Where it is defined? I think this is what causes the error

Comment: here: ```std::string letter; std::getline(std::cin, letter);```

Comment: @Aftermathic If so, then the error in `letter == a[1]` since you're comparing between two different types `char vs std::string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `{"A", "a"}` is already a verctor, and this `array` varable type should be `vector<vector<string>>`.

Comment: Yes, using pair is more fit than vector.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you initialize your strings. The following fails as well:

```
std::string s {"A", "a"};
```

`"A"` and `"a"` are of type `const char*` and represent two characters each (the letter, and a null terminator `'\0'`).

What you probably want is to initialize your strings with `char` elements instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> array = {
    {'A', 'a'},
    {'B', 'b'},
    {'C', 'c'}
};
```

Note the single quotes `'`.
You can also just do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> array = {
    "Aa",
    "Bb",
    "Cc"
};
```